# Testing different versions of IE using Watir

Tags: internet-explorer, watir

Is it possible to set the document mode and the browser mode, while testing IE9 with Watir? In short could I test my site, in an emulated version of IE browser. Like say IE7 or IE8?

I want to test my site in different versions of IE. I have IE9 installed. Using the developer toolbar I usually switch between different versions. Could the same behavior be replicated using Watir?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you create several virtual machines. Each one of them has different version of Internet Explorer: 6, 7, 8, 9. That is what I do.

Comment: That's what we do as well - different version of Safari/Chrome/Firefox/IE on each box.

Comment: +1 from me also.  VM's are cheap and easy and can be reset easily to a known state.  Also with the approach you were proposing, are you really testing your site on IExx or are you testing IE9's ability to emulate version xx while displaying your site?  If something is wrong, was it your code or IE9?  you'd have to always go and verify on the real thing, so why not just test there in the first place